# Deploying Jenkins Sectioned View Plugin extension

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to create new view for Sectioned View Plugin for Jenkins. How should I deploy my extension? I was trying to deploy it as new plugin in .jpi file but it didn't work. Where should I put my class/jar/jpi (I don't know which is right) file?

UPD: I tried to put jar to \jenkins\plugin\sectioned-view\WEB-INF\lib directory and it works but I doubt it's a right way to deploy that extension

UPD2: When I try to deploy extension as a new plugin I get these exception on startup:

```
WARNING: Failed to load <packageName>.<mainExtensionClassName>$DescriptorImpl
java.lang.InstantiationException:<jenkinsDirectory>\plugins\installedapplicationssection\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar might need to be rebuilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <packageName>.<mainExtensionClassName>$DescriptorImpl
at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:144)
at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz._find(ExtensionFinder.java:628)
at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.find(ExtensionFinder.java:617)
at hudson.ExtensionFinder._find(ExtensionFinder.java:151)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:316)
at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:309)
at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
at hudson.ExtensionList.get(ExtensionList.java:153)
at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:1109)
at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:906)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <packageName>.<mainExtensionClassName>$DescriptorImpl
at hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader.findClass(PluginManager.java:985)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:134)
```

But I already have this in my class:
    @Extension
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends SectionedViewSectionDescriptor {

```
    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "My Section";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. "I was trying to deploy it as new plugin in .jpi file but it didn't work." how do you know that it didn't work? Do you have error messages in the log file? Try to give as much info as possible, so that someone can actually help you.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze added exception from log

Comment: Thats what you need to fix. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <packageName>.<mainExtensionClassName>$DescriptorImpl`